# variavel do tipo post não carrega

Tags: php, html, post

Muito boa noite eu estou desenvolvendo um chat (para estudo) e eu fiz um formulário para mandar as mensagens como sempre faço porem o arquivo php não carrega no servidor local da o erro http 500 que normalmente é ocorrido quando tem um erro no arquivo porem já até testei no cmd e não encontrou nada

se alguém puder ajudar agradeço

index.php

```
<form method="post" action="php/insert.php">
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                            <input type="text" name="mensagem" class="form-control" placeholder="Sua mensagem"  aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
                          <div class="input-group-append">
                            <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit">Enviar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

insert.php

```
<?php 
    session_start();
     include("connect.php");     

        $id = isset($_SESSION['id']) ? $_SESSION['id'] : '';
        $nome = isset($_SESSION['name']) ? $_SESSION['name'] : '';      


        if(!empty($id) && !empty($nome) && !empty($_POST["mensagem"])){     

        $sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO conversas (mensagem, id, nome) VALUES (':mensagem', ':id', ':nome')");
        $sql->bindValue(":mensagem", $_POST["mensagem"]);
        $sql->bindValue(":id",$id);
        $sql->bindValue(":nome", $nome);
        $sql->execute();

        header('location: ../index.php');
        }else {
            $_SESSION['mensagem-not'] = 'É preciso escrever a mensagem';
            header('location: ../index.php');
        }
?>
```

connect.php

```
<?php   
    $usr = "root";
    $pwd = "j21042005J$";  


    try {
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=chatsimples', $usr, $pwd);
          $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
      } catch(PDOException $e) {
          echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
      }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que o erro possa ser por você não estar setando a variável $pdo adequadamente, pois você está setando a variável $pdo dentro do try-catch connect.php, mas quando você tenta usa-la no insert.php ela não foi setada no escopo global, então o objeto em

```
$sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO conversas (mensagem, id, nome) VALUES (':mensagem', ':id', ':nome')");
```

está nulo.

Tente adicionar $pdo = null; no inicio do arquivo connect.php junto com o user e o password, ai ela será iniciada no try-catch e poderá ser usada no $sql.

Vale tambem você setar o

> display_errors = On

No PHP.ini para verificar estes erros com mais detalhes.

Comment: Opa muito obrigado eu testei aqui e deu certo